# Viewstate updated by a reference to a cast obj?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm keeping a small DataSet in a Viewstate as shown below and want to know why it's being updated.

intId is a string that is passed into the method.  When a match happens the row is deleted in DataSet ds, but the Viewstate is also updated at the same time. Confused on why. Is it a reference issue?

```
           DataSet ds = (DataSet)ViewState["DataSet"];

           foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                var intId = row[0].ToString();                   

                if (roleID.ToString() == intId)
                {
                    row.Delete();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hi, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3583585/2177589
BiewState is a reference type, that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following events, **ViewState** and **ds** references to same memory location. *(It is why changes in ds effects ViewState.)*

- Page Load
- Control Events
- Pre-Render

Then ViewState is serialized and saved into a base-64 encoded string. 
*After Pre-Render event, changes in **ds** doesn't effect ViewState anymore.*

You can read more about ViewState here - [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Before it serializes, the ViewState will contain the actual reference to your DataSet object.  On PostBack, after deserialization, it is a brand new instance of a DataSet.